# Какой плагин используют на полит. серверах майнкрафт

Tags: сервер, плагин, minecraft

Какой плагин используют для отметки территории игроков на динамической карте сервера?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что поиск плагинов для Майнкрафта это оффтопик

Answer (score 1):

Аддон для Dynmap поможет решить вашу проблему
https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/dynmap-worldguard

Comment: За что минус, дал же ссылку на плагин.

Comment: Был по тому, что весь ответ это переписанный вопрос. Убрал